# Strange Windows DIR command behavior

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd, dir

I discovered this quite by accident while looking for a file with a number in the name.  When I type:

**`dir`** `*`*number*`*`

(where number represents any number from 0 to 9 and with no spaces between the asterisks and the number)

at the cmd.exe command prompt, it returns various files do not appear in any to fit the search criteria.  What's weird, is that depending on the directory, some numbers will work and not others.  An example is, in a directory associated with a website, I type the following:

```
dir *4*
```

and what is returned is:

```
Directory of C:\Ampps\www\includes\pages 

04/30/2012  03:55 PM               153 inventory_list_retrieve.php
06/18/2012  11:17 AM             6,756 ix.html
06/19/2012  01:47 PM           257,501 jquery.1.7.1.js
               3 File(s)        264,410 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  362,280,906,752 bytes free
```

That just doesn't make any sense to me.  Any clue?

The question is posed on stackOverflow because the DIR command is often combined with FOR in batch programs. The strange DIR behavior would seem to make batch programs potentially unreliable if they use the DIR command.

Edit: (additional note). Though much time has passed, I discovered another quirk with this that almost cost me a lot of work.  I wanted to delete all `.htm` files in a particular directory tree.  I realized just before doing it that `*.htm` matches `.html` files as well.  Also, `*.man` matches `.manifest`, and there are probably others.  Deleting all `.html` files in that particular directory would have been upsetting to say the least.

Comment: Interesting! We need to do some test about this matter...

Comment: Wow, after all these years - still amazed by this technology. I can confirm that strange behaviour.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/336358/is-it-a-good-idea-to-disable-short-filenames-on-windows-7-running-on-a-ssd-drive

Comment: Although the question does not explicitly address batch programming, the underlying problem has profound implications for batch programming. Please do not close this question on the grounds that it does not relate to programming.

Comment: If the ability existed to vote against a vote to close I would. If the question is closed, I would vote to reopen. This is touching an underlying issue with the Windows API as exposed both at the command prompt and in batch files. IMHO it is clearly on-topic for the batch and cmd tags.

Comment: Please show some of what you're using to call dir from the batch file, so this doesn't get migrated again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wild cards at the command prompt are matched against both the long file name and the short "8.3" name if one is present. This can produce surprises.

To see the short names, use the `/X` option to the `DIR` command.

Note that this behavior is not in any way specific to the `DIR` command, and can lead to other (often unpleasant) surprises when a wild card matches more than expected on any command, such as `DEL`.

Unlike in *nix shells, replacement of a file pattern with the list of matching names is implemented within each command and not implemented by the shell itself. This can mean that different commands could implement different wild card pattern rules, but in practice this is quite rare as Windows provides API calls to search a directory for files that match a pattern and most programs use those calls in the obvious way. For programs written in C or C++ using the "usual" tools, that expansion is provided "for free" by the C runtime library, using the Windows API.

The Windows API in question is [`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its close relatives [`FindFirstFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`FindNextFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx), and [`FindClose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413(v=vs.85).aspx).

Oddly, although the documentation for `FindFirstFile()` describes its lpFileName parameter as "directory or path, and the file name, which can include wildcard characters, for example, an asterisk (`*`) or a question mark (`?`)" it never actually defines what the `*` and `?` characters mean.

The exact meaning of the file pattern has history in the [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) operating system dating from the early 1970s that strongly influenced (some might say "was directly copied" in place of "influenced" here) the design of MSDOS. This has resulted in a number of "interesting" artifacts and behaviors. Some of this at the DOS end of the spectrum is described at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) from 2007 where Raymond describes exactly how file patters were implemented in DOS.

Answer (score 13):

Yep. You'll see that it also searches through short names if you try this:

```
dir /x *4*
```

(/x switch is for short names)

for filtering file names use :

```
dir /b | find "4"
```

Comment: if you want a searh ONLY in long names use  | find

Comment: +1, Yes, the "hidden" short file names can cause problems that are not obvious. The suggestion to use FIND should work: `dir /b | find "4"`. The use of FINDSTR instead would allow more selective filtering via regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

A quote from RBerteig's answer:

> Note that this behavior is not in any way specific to the DIR command,
>   and can lead to other (often unpleasant) surprises when a wild card
>   matches more than expected on any command, such as DEL.

The above is true even for the FOR command, which is very nasty.

```
for %A in (*4*) do @echo %A contains a 4
```

will also search the short names. The solution again would be to use FIND or FINDSTR to filter out the names in a more reliable manner.

```
for %A in (*) do @echo %A | >nul findstr 4 && echo %A contains a 4
```

*Note - change %A to %%A if using the command within a batch file.*

Combining FOR with FINDSTR can be a general purpose method to safely use any command that runs into problems with short file names. Simply replace ECHO with the problem command such as COPY or DEL.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like dir command searches also short ( 8.3 manner ) file names under the hood.

When I call `dir *1*` this is what I get:

```
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is F061-0B78

 Directory of C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop\Downloads
2012-05-20  17:33        23 639 040 gDEBugger-5_8.msi
2012-05-20  17:30           761 942 glew-1.7.0.zip
2012-05-20  17:11         9 330 176 irfanview_plugins_433_setup.exe
2012-05-24  20:17         4 419 192 SumatraPDF-2.1.1-install.exe
2012-05-15  22:55         3 466 248 TrueCrypt Setup 7.1a.exe
               5 File(s)  1 127 302 494 bytes
```

There is a `gDEBugger-5_8.msi` file amongst listed ones, which apparently does not have any `1` character in it.

Everything becomes clear when I use `/X` switch with the dir command, which makes dir use 8.3 file names. Output from a `dir /X *1*` command:

```
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is F061-0B78

 Directory of C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop\Downloads


2012-05-20  17:33        23 639 040 GDEBUG~1.MSI gDEBugger-5_8.msi
2012-05-20  17:30           761 942 GLEW-1~1.ZIP glew-1.7.0.zip
2012-05-20  17:11         9 330 176 IRFANV~1.EXE irfanview_plugins_433_setup.exe
2012-05-24  20:17         4 419 192 SUMATR~1.EXE SumatraPDF-2.1.1-install.exe
2012-05-15  22:55         3 466 248 TRUECR~1.EXE TrueCrypt Setup 7.1a.exe
               5 File(s)  1 127 302 494 bytes
```

Quote from dir's help:

```
/X          This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file
            names.  The format is that of /N with the short name inserted
            before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are
            displayed in its place.
```