# The command prompt does not handle wild cards correctly

Tags: directory, command, prompt

As I have understood it the command dir C:\kat\subkat\20*.* should result in a list of all files in C:\kat\subkat\ with 20 as the first characters in the filename. In my computer I don't get all files. However, I get all files with a date for latest change beginning with 20. Have anyone seen some thing similar?
When trying to use this method for copying with XCOPY, I get an immense number of files copied. Very few of them are files in C:\kat\subkat\ with 20 as the first characters in the filename. What has happened? What can I do?
I have Windows 7 on an HP Probook6470b.

Answer (score 0):

Dir command have a MS-DOS legacy, which carry a CP/M one.
[Dir command history](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx)

The behavior can be unexpected for files whose name contains spaces, have more than 12 characters, or the extension is longer than 3 characters.

And that's because the generated 8.3 short names
This [Rules for 8.3 short names](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142982) gives a clue about how short names are generated, but is not exhaustive.
Please see my example below for some hints

When the folder or computer searched with dir support short names, **files whose short name respect the mask, will be included** in the final result.

Moreover, the result include files whose short name contains characters included in the mask, *even these characters are not part of the long name*.

A classic example is the ~1(2,3..) suffix
[How affect short names the DIR result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107044/strange-windows-dir-command-behavior)

This behavior can be stopped, by removing the support for short names.

Examples.
Supposing your folder contains

```
aabb.xl
aa bb.xl
aabb.xls
aa bb.xls
aabb.xlsx
aa bb.xlsx
aabb.xlsxp
aa bb.xlsxp
aabb.xlsxpm
aa bb.xlsxpm
```

On my PC, this is the result of
Example 1)

```
DIR a*.* /x
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AABB~1.XL    aa bb.xl
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AABB~1.XLS   aa bb.xls
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AABB~3.XLS   aa bb.xlsx
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AA3C12~1.XLS aa bb.xlsxp
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AA96D4~1.XLS aa bb.xlsxpm
17.09.2015  10:35                 0              aabb.xl
17.09.2015  10:35                 0              aabb.xls
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AABB~2.XLS   aabb.xlsx
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AABB~4.XLS   aabb.xlsxp
17.09.2015  10:35                 0 AA84DD~1.XLS aabb.xlsxpm
```

Example 2)

```
DIR "*b*.xls" /x
aabb.xls
aa bb.xls
aabb.xlsx
aa bb.xlsx
aabb.xlsxp
```

Example 3)

```
DIR "*b*.xl?" /x
aabb.xl
aa bb.xl
aabb.xls
aa bb.xls
aabb.xlsx
aa bb.xlsx
aabb.xlsxp
```

Example 4)

```
DIR "*D*.xls" /x
aa bb.xlsxpm aka AA96D4~1.XLS
aabb.xlsxpm aka AA84DD~1.XLS
```

Example 5)

```
DIR "??????.xls" /x
aabb.xls
aa bb.xls aka AABB~1.XLS
aabb.xlsx aka AABB~2.XLS
aa bb.xlsx aka AABB~3.XLS
aabb.xlsxp aka AABB~4.XLS
```

Comment: Thank you very much a comprehensive answer!
Do you know any program I can use for copying and moving files, which works more as one would expect with long filenames?